# cannot paste external files into a ntfs file system in Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: dual-boot, cp, copy-and-paste, ntfs-3g

on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS I have an NTFS data partition. This is a dual boot system with Windows 10. The option "paste" is grayed out when I try to copy-paste into the NTFS partition any file that is located anywhere **outside** of the partition. However, if I try to copy the very same file (outside of the partition) into the very same partition from the command line using `cp`, that works without any problem. Similarly, if I try to copy-paste into the partition any file that is already inside the partition, the "paste" button is not grayed out and works with no issue.

I have already checked that my user `xis` is the owner of the partition, and that it has rw access to it.

```
xis@etna:/media$ ls -ali
total 12
6553601 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 dic  9  2021 .
      2 drwxr-xr-x  20 root root 4096 apr 28 20:28 ..
6553602 drwxrwxrwx+  3 xis  xis  4096 lug 25 16:12 xis
xis@etna:/media$ ls -ali ./xis
total 12
6553602 drwxrwxrwx+ 3 xis  xis  4096 lug 25 16:12 .
6553601 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 dic  9  2021 ..
      5 drwxrwxrwx  1 xis  xis  4096 lug 26 16:58 data
```

The file system is mounted on fstab with the following options (which give `xis` rw access):

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4      /media/xis/data ntfs-3g uid=xis,gid=xis,auto,suid,dev,rw,user,exec  0   2
```

File-system check on Linux returned no errors:

```
xis@etna:/media$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p4
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/nvme0n1p4 was processed successfully.
```

File-system check on Windows found and repaired some issues (not clear what), but that did not fix my problem.

"Fast startup" is disabled on Windows.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I found out the problem. I was trying to copy-paste files from the Desktop. That functionality has been disabled in the current version of GNOME. If I try to copy file from anywhere else, copy-paste into the partition works. So it was not a problem of the partition or the permissions, it was simply a problem related with this new GNOME design that does not allow to copy-paste. [Here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/10/enable-drag-drop-desktop-ubuntu-20-04/) is a way of enabling drag-&-drop. But I still did not find a way to enable copy-paste into/from the Desktop (and not from the Desktop folder) in GNOME. If anybody knows, please let me know.

Comment: Is hybernation enabled in Windows? If so, disable it, restart Windows for the changes to have effect. If it is already disabled it has to do with permissions.

Comment: Thanks. Hybernation is disabled. I also thought it was about permissions, but as you can see from my post, permissions are set to 777 to anybody on the /media/xis/data folder. Or is there something else? Also, how can it be about permissions if the same user (xis) can copy a file into that drive from the command line using cp?